# Subtract value to the nearest specific string in another column

Tags: r

Let say I have a data `df` as below. In total, there are 20 rows and there are four types of strings in column `string`: "A", "B", "C" and "D".

```
no  string  position
1   B   650
2   C   651
3   B   659
4   C   660
5   C   662
6   B   663
7   D   668
8   D   670
9   C   671
10  B   672
11  C   673
12  A   681
13  C   682
14  B   683
15  C   684
16  D   690
17  A   692
18  C   693
19  D   694
20  C   695
```

By performing subtraction of value in column `position` from the previous row, I could get a forth column `distance` by executing the following command:

```
df$distance <- ave(df$position, FUN=function(x) c(0, diff(x)))
```

So that I could get distance from the current value to the previous row as below:

```
no  string  position    distance
1   B   650 0
2   C   651 1
3   B   659 8
4   C   660 1
5   C   662 2
6   B   663 1
7   D   668 5
8   D   670 2
9   C   671 1
10  B   672 1
11  C   673 1
12  A   681 8
13  C   682 1
14  B   683 1
15  C   684 1
16  D   690 6
17  A   692 2
18  C   693 1
19  D   694 1
20  C   695 1
```

However, what I wish to have is to get the distance in `column position` for each string to the nearest previous string "C", such as the change of **7,8 and 17** below:

```
no  string  position    distance
1   B   650 0
2   C   651 1
3   B   659 8
4   C   660 1
5   C   662 2
6   B   663 1
7   D   668 6
8   D   670 8
9   C   671 1
10  B   672 1
11  C   673 1
12  A   681 8
13  C   682 1
14  B   683 1
15  C   684 1
16  D   690 6
17  A   692 8
18  C   693 1
19  D   694 1
20  C   695 1
```

How can I do so? By the way, can I know how I can do to get the distance from the **nearest next "C"** in column `string` as well?

Comment: @RonakShah  My apologies. I have a typo in the table and already corrected it.

Comment: *"get the distance in column position for each string to the nearest previous string "C", such as the change of 7,8 and 17 below"* I'm sorry but I really struggle to understand your expected output and what you're trying to calculate. Are you asking after string distances (i.e. how many letters are e.g. D and A apart)? What does the letter "C" have to do with it? Is that just an example? Or is "C" the reference letter? The "change of 7,8  and 17" refer to what values? I don't see a value 17 anywhere.

Comment: [continued] It might help if you could detail the calculation of `distance` for the first 5 rows.

Comment: Hi @MauritsEvers. My apologies for confusion. For example, at row (no.) 17 the `position` value is 692 for an `string` "A" (non "C"). I wish to get the subtraction from the nearest previous "C" which is row 15 at position 684. So I would like to have the value of 692 - 684 = 8 for column `distance` instead of 2 which I could only get by subtracting the previous row. I wish to do this for every non "C" with its nearest previous C. Hope that this clarifies.

Comment: Can't you just initialize `df$distance <- NA` and then for each letter do: `df$distance[df$string == LETTERS[i]] <- ave(df$position[df$string == LETTERS[i]], FUN=function(x) c(0, diff(x)))` ?

Comment: @bison72 Still confused. Why is `distance = 1` for row 4, and `distance = 2` for row 5? Both rows have `string = "C"`? Also why is `distance = 1` for row 2 where `string = "C"` and there is no previous `"C"`?

Comment: @MauritsEvers basically it is if `string == "C"` then calculate difference from previous row or else calculate difference from the nearest "C" row. I don't know why I wrote such a lengthy answer though . :|

Comment: @RonakShah Aaaah ok, I'm getting there slowly (I think). Wow, that's not clear *at all* from OPs problem statement. Should've read your answer more thoroughly;-)

Comment: @bison72 Please consider closing the question by setting the green check mark next to one of the answers below. That way you help future SO readers, and keep SO tidy.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not an ideal solution and there is a way to simplify this.

```
#Taken from your code
df$distance <- ave(df$position, FUN=function(x) c(0, diff(x)))

#logical values indicating occurrence of "C" 
c_occur = df$string == "C"

#We can ignore first two values in each group since, 
#First value is "C" and second value is correctly calculated from previous row
#Get the indices where we need to replace the values
inds_to_replace = which(ave(df$string, cumsum(c_occur), FUN = seq_along) > 2)

#Get the closest occurrence of "C" from the inds_to_replace
c_to_replace <- sapply(inds_to_replace, function(x) {
          new_inds <- which(c_occur)
          max(new_inds[(x - new_inds) > 0])
#To get distance from "nearest next "C" replace the above line with 
          #new_inds[which.max(x - new_inds < 0)]
})

#Replace the values
df$distance[inds_to_replace] <- df$position[inds_to_replace] - 
                                df$position[c_to_replace]

df[inds_to_replace, ]

#   no string position distance
#7   7      D      668        6
#8   8      D      670        8
#17 17      A      692        8
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `data.table` way:

```
dtt[, distance := c(0, diff(position))]
dtt[cumsum(string == 'C') > 0,
    distance := ifelse(seq_len(.N) == 1, distance, position - position[1]),
    by = cumsum(string == 'C')]

#     no string position distance
#  1:  1      B      650        0
# 2:  2      C      651        1
# 3:  3      B      659        8
# 4:  4      C      660        1
# 5:  5      C      662        2
# 6:  6      B      663        1
# 7:  7      D      668        6
# 8:  8      D      670        8
# 9:  9      C      671        1
# 10: 10      B      672        1
# 11: 11      C      673        1
# 12: 12      A      681        8
# 13: 13      C      682        1
# 14: 14      B      683        1
# 15: 15      C      684        1
# 16: 16      D      690        6
# 17: 17      A      692        8
# 18: 18      C      693        1
# 19: 19      D      694        1
# 20: 20      C      695        1
```

Here is `dtt`:

```
structure(list(no = 1:20, string = c("B", "C", "B", "C", "C", 
"B", "D", "D", "C", "B", "C", "A", "C", "B", "C", "D", "A", "C", 
"D", "C"), position = c(650L, 651L, 659L, 660L, 662L, 663L, 668L, 
670L, 671L, 672L, 673L, 681L, 682L, 683L, 684L, 690L, 692L, 693L, 
694L, 695L)), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x1939260>)
```

If you want to get distance to nearest next `C` for non-`C` rows, try this:

```
dtt[, distance := c(0, diff(position))]
dtt[, g := rev(cumsum(rev(string == 'C')))]
dtt[g > 0, distance := ifelse(seq_len(.N) == .N, distance, abs(position - position[.N])), by = g]
dtt[, g := NULL]
#     no string position distance
#  1:  1      B      650        1
#  2:  2      C      651        1
#  3:  3      B      659        1
#  4:  4      C      660        1
#  5:  5      C      662        2
#  6:  6      B      663        8
#  7:  7      D      668        3
#  8:  8      D      670        1
#  9:  9      C      671        1
# 10: 10      B      672        1
# 11: 11      C      673        1
# 12: 12      A      681        1
# 13: 13      C      682        1
# 14: 14      B      683        1
# 15: 15      C      684        1
# 16: 16      D      690        3
# 17: 17      A      692        1
# 18: 18      C      693        1
# 19: 19      D      694        1
# 20: 20      C      695        1
```

Answer (score 0):

The following `tidyverse` approach reproduces your expected output.

Problem description: Calculate the difference in `position` of the current row with the *previous* `string = "C"` row; if there is no previous `string = "C"` row or the row itself has `string = "C"`, then the distance is given by the difference in `position` between the current and previous row (irrespective of `string`).

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
    mutate(nC = cumsum(string == "C")) %>%
    group_by(nC) %>%
    mutate(dist = cumsum(c(0, diff(position)))) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    mutate(dist = if_else(dist == 0, c(0, diff(position)), dist)) %>%
    select(-nC)
## A tibble: 20 x 4
#      no string position  dist
#   <int> <fct>     <int> <dbl>
# 1     1 B           650    0.
# 2     2 C           651    1.
# 3     3 B           659    8.
# 4     4 C           660    1.
# 5     5 C           662    2.
# 6     6 B           663    1.
# 7     7 D           668    6.
# 8     8 D           670    8.
# 9     9 C           671    1.
#10    10 B           672    1.
#11    11 C           673    1.
#12    12 A           681    8.
#13    13 C           682    1.
#14    14 B           683    1.
#15    15 C           684    1.
#16    16 D           690    6.
#17    17 A           692    8.
#18    18 C           693    1.
#19    19 D           694    1.
#20    20 C           695    1.
```

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.table(text =
"no  string  position
1   B   650
2   C   651
3   B   659
4   C   660
5   C   662
6   B   663
7   D   668
8   D   670
9   C   671
10  B   672
11  C   673
12  A   681
13  C   682
14  B   683
15  C   684
16  D   690
17  A   692
18  C   693
19  D   694
20  C   695", header = T)
```